# Is it a good idea to replace Angular-Translate module with a simple object with key-value pairs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angular-translate

I have an [Angular app](https://angularjs.org/) that uses the [translate module](https://angular-translate.github.io/). I've read that there are some performance implications related to both two-way binding and DOM filters. As of today, I'm using both and I think that impacts my app's overall performance.

**In HTML:**

```
<!-- Example of two-way binding + DOM filtering -->
{{ 'TranslationId' | translate }}
```

I read that an easy work-around would be the following:

**In JavaScript:**

```
// Use the filter in the controller, not in the view
$scope.translationId = $translate.instant('TranslationId');
```

**In HTML:**

```
<!-- Use one-way binding to avoid odd watchers -->
 {{  ::translationId  }}
```

Okay. That's good but after reading this, I found myself making a big list of scope variables that are using $translate.instant and I asked myself the following question:

> Is there a strong reason in using Angular Translate this way?

First, sending a JSON from the server to the client. Then loading this JSON, and then storing almost all of this JSON's properties in new variables.

So..

> Can I skip all of this and just keep a big translations' object that's global to all my views?
>
> *Having in mind that I'm not actually using one of the best features of the angular translate module - changing language on the client side.*

**Of course, I can, but the question is whether there's a strong reason of not doing so.**

Comment: Starting with the initial premise: is it actually *too slow* for you just using regular `translate` filters…?!

Comment: @deceze Honestly, I haven't found a proper way of measuring how long the translate filters in my app actually take yet. I was just looking for ways to improve the performance of the app, as I have too many ng-repeats, filters and unnecessary two-way bindings in it. 

Any ideas how to measure the exact time, because I was unable to find something useful up to now?

Comment: Simplest possible way: remove all the `translate` directives, time it, put the directives back, time it, check the difference. Decide whether it *makes* a noticeable difference.

Comment: Yeap, I'm trying this and I'm measuring by looking at the Dev Tools Profiler - measuring just apply and digest. Better ideas again?